# facebox form submission

Tags: jquery, facebox

I'm loading a page dynamically into facebox which has a form, I need it to be able to be submit the form without facebox closing / redirecting.

I've seen several forums about using ajax, is there a way to do it without ajax, the reason being is becuase the code has already been done already, and the form uses a captcha etc.

Any ideas.

Cheers

Shane

Comment: Does facebox put it's content in an Iframe? Yes it can be done with ajax...

Comment: No it's not in an iframe.. I want to avoid ajax if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution: see here: http://keyzo.co.uk/blog/facebox-form-submission/